# eclipse birt report page removal

Tags: birt

I want to remove specific pages in my birt report.
the reason is that I have 20 charts and some of them, sometimes, have no data.
so when I make it invisible, the page is shown empty. this why I want to remove it.

I can pass a parameter from the java file to tell the report which page to remove. but how do I remove it?
is there a way to do it? a script that I can add to my report?

thanks a lot, 
Yoni.

Answer (score 1):

You have make the element invisible that reserves the space for the chart. Mostly it is in a grid-cell where you have entered a specific height. If this is the case you have to set the entire row of the grid to invisible.

Comment: thanks @tom. Ive already tried making the grid invisible. that works but the empty pages are still there.  Ive wrote for example: `if(pageNumber == 1){
this.getStyle().display ="none"
} `

Comment: @yoni Did you make sure that all your elements have a dynamic height? - It's mostly the problem that one element in you hierarchie has a fixed height which will generate too much space...

Comment: can it be because of page breaks after each element?   Im having 6 grids that each one include 2 charts. and after each grid I placed a pagebreak.